# Regex in MongoDB raw_query

Tags: mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

How will I apply regex on mongo db's raw_query? 
I tried

```
{'foo.bar': {$regex:'.*test.*'}}
```

but django shell complained for an invalid syntax.

I also tried

```
{'foo.bar': '.*test.*'}
```

assuming that the regex will take effect. But the result is empty

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try quoting as in `"$regex"`

Answer (score 0):

It's (also) `{ "foo.bar": /.*test.*/ }` on the shell - have you tried that? See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/